# Owl carousel fancy box addition and image link

Tags: php, html, wordpress, fancybox, owl-carousel

I have a Owl carousel which is working fine but it's just a static carousel and I want it to be in a fancy box when an image gets click it'll open up in full size with the carousel exactly [like this](https://codepen.io/jeetenbargaiya/pen/RBZYvX)

Here is my code so far I'm having trouble getting link the images to the urls based on the image ID and add it with fancybox.

```
<div class="col-md-5">
<div class="gallery_wrap">
      <div id="model-gallery" class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
      <?php $featured_image = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id(get_the_ID()), 'model-featured-image' );
            if($featured_image == ''){
                $featured_image = '';
        } ?>
        
        <div class="card">
        <a data-fancybox="fancyframe" href="<?php echo get_permalink($image_id); ?>">
        <img class="card-img-top" src="<?php echo $featured_image; ?>" alt="Card image cap">
        </a>
        </div>
        <?php
        $model_images = get_field('gallery');
        $image_size = 'full';

        if( $model_images ):  
        foreach( $model_images as $image_id ):?>
        <div class="card">
        <a data-fancybox="fancyframe" href="<?php echo get_permalink($image_id); ?>">
        <img class="card-img-top" src="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_image_url( $image_id, $image_size ); ?>" alt="<?php the_title();?>">
        </a>
        
        </div>
        <?php endforeach; endif;?>
      </div>
</div>
```

UPDATE: I'm able to make the images clickable and open up the fancybox but when an image is clicked it shows the error inside fancybox :The requested content cannot be loaded. Please try again.

Also the console is showing this error:
Uncaught TypeError: n(...).appendTo(...).hide(...).fadeIn is not a function
at b.showLoading (jquery.fancybox.min.js:11:25512)
at jquery.fancybox.min.js:11:20479

Comment: To make ```fancybox``` running you should put your images into ```<a>``` tag with a specific class e.g. ```"gallery"```, where ```href``` attribute is the path to the full image. Then you just run it by js ```$().fancybox({selector: 'a.gallery',});```

Comment: Thank you for your comment @Lothric I'm stuck with href how do I get the href url?

Comment: I'm not familiar with WordPress, but as I see, it should be something like ```<a class="gallery" href="<?= wp_get_attachment_image_url( $image_id, $image_size ); ?>"><img src="<?= wp_get_attachment_image_url( $image_id, 'medium' ); ?>"></a>```

Comment: The thing is that fancybox should accelerate loading speed, because there are small images on the page. And full images are available on click. Of course you can put original images in the ```img``` of you want to, just change the size from ```medium``` to ```full```

Comment: I have used this code to get the url corrrect based on the clicked image but when an image is clicked it's redirecting to the image url in a new tab.

`<a class="gallery" href="<?php echo get_permalink($image_id); ?>"><img class="card-img-top" src="<?php echo wp_get_attachment_image_url( $image_id, $image_size ); ?>" alt="<?php the_title();?>"></a>`

Comment: And did you connect fancybox lib and write that to your ```js``` section ```$().fancybox({selector: 'a.gallery',});```?

Comment: Yes I did, I have added that to the js file

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246261/discussion-between-lothric-and-imran-irshad).